# ParseExact string to DateTime

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I try to parse my string to datetime, but I get a FormatException.

```
string date = "27.02.2017 13:03:16 Uhr";  
action.Date = 
    DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Does somebody has any idea?

Comment: `"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss 'Uhr'"`, `Exact` means exact...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the "Uhr" at the end of the input. If you specify your format like this, the input must match the format.

After some people add "Uhr" and some people don't, I recommend to extract the relevant part using a regex.

```cs
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Match m = Regex.Match( @"/([\d]{2}\.[\d]{2}\.[\d]{4} +[\d]{2}\:[\d]{2}\:[\d]{2})/", date);
if (m != null)
    date = m.Groups[0].Value;
else
    // Something wrong with the input here
```

And then (unless m is null) you can use this string as a valid input for your ParseExact-part in most cases. But be aware that the regex does not perform any range-checks, so an input like `Montag, 99.99.9999 99:99:99 Uhr` would lead to the date string `99.99.9999 99:99:99` which matches the regex, but is not a valid DateTime anyway.

Answer (score 5):

You have to escape `Uhr` suffix:

```
  string date = "27.02.2017 13:03:16 Uhr";
  action.Date = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss 'Uhr'",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```